# how make addition from 2 variable twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Anyone knows how to addition two variable in twig I want to do something like:

{{ var1 }} + {{ var2 }}

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just do it inside the `{{ }}`

```
{{ var1 + var2 }}
```

If you want to assign it to some other variable:

```
{% set foo = var1 + var2 %}
{{ foo }}
```

Answer (score 15):

Declaration :

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
```

Doing the addition :

```
{% set counter = counter + 1 %}
```

For displaying in twig template :

```
{{ counter }}
```

Comment: Helped! Thanks!!

Comment: Worth clarifying the obvious that this example is best used in loops and the accepted answer for general addition with variables :)