# Twig Assignment operator

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to calculate total numbers for a specific field in Twig

in Php Template, I can easily make it like so

```
  <?php $tl = 0; ?>
  <?php foreach($loo as $l):>
  <?php $tl += $l['amount'] ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $l['amount'] ?>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

  <p><?php echo number_format($tl,2) ?>
```

How to do it in Twig?

I tried

```
 {% set tl = 0 %}
    {% for task in tasks %}
       {% set tl += {{ task.amount }} %} 
    {% endfor %}
    {{ tl }}
```

It doesn't work
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like twig doesn't support combined operators as PHP do.
(I could not find an example in http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#setting-variables)

Maybe this is relevant:
[how make addition from 2 variable twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269622/how-make-addition-from-2-variable-twig)

Could you try a separate operator version?

```
{% set tl = tl + task.amount %}
```